# Trigger not firing when deleting a record from stored procedure MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

Bare with me, as I'm fairly new to stored procedures / triggers.

I have the following Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`serveraddress` PROCEDURE `TASK_APPROVE`(IN idtask INT, IN idrevised INT, IN idapproved INT)

ROOT:BEGIN
    DECLARE SQL_EXCEPTION INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE rpi_number_draft varchar(20);
    DECLARE id_primary_draft INT;
    DECLARE FETCH_STATUS INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE id_primary_live, revision_live, num_rows INT;
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    #Create Cursor to iterate through all rpis in draft
    DECLARE rpiDraftCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT  `id_primary`, `number` 
        FROM    `rpi_procedures` 
        WHERE   `id_task` = idtask;

    #Create Loop Handler to determine when all records in the cursor have been iterated through    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET FETCH_STATUS = 100;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING SET SQL_EXCEPTION = 100;
        SELECT  `id_primary`, `number` 
        FROM    `rpi_procedures` 
        WHERE   `id_task` = idtask;
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;
    SET counter = 0;
    OPEN rpiDraftCursor;

    #Loop through all records in the rpiDraftCursor
    draft_loop:WHILE (FETCH_STATUS = 0) DO
        #Get First Record From Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM rpiDraftCursor
        INTO id_primary_draft, rpi_number_draft;

        BEGIN
            DECLARE live_rows_returned INT;
            START TRANSACTION;
                SELECT  `id_primary`, `revision`
                FROM    `rpi_procedures`
                WHERE   `number` = rpi_number_draft
                AND     `id_status` = 1 
                INTO id_primary_live, revision_live;

                SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO live_rows_returned;
                #live_rows_returned will equal zero if its a new rpi
                IF live_rows_returned = 0 THEN
                    SET id_primary_live = id_primary_draft;
                    SET revision_live = -1;
                END IF;

                IF (counter < num_rows) THEN
                    UPDATE  `rpi_procedures`
                    SET     `id_previous` = id_primary_live,
                            `revision` = revision_live + 1,
                            `id_revised` = idrevised,
                            `id_approved` = idapproved,
                            `id_status` = 1,
                            `id_task` = 0
                    WHERE   `id_primary` = id_primary_draft;    

                    IF live_rows_returned > 0 THEN
                        DELETE  
                        FROM    `rpi_procedures`
                        WHERE   `id_primary` = id_primary_live;     
                    END IF;
                END IF;
                IF SQL_EXCEPTION = 100 THEN
                    ROLLBACK;
                END IF;
                SET counter = counter + 1;
            COMMIT;
        END;        

        #If Loop Handler = 100 Exit Loop
        IF FETCH_STATUS = 100 THEN
            LEAVE draft_loop;
        END IF;

    End WHILE draft_loop;

    CLOSE rpiDraftCursor;
    SET FETCH_STATUS = 0;   

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And I have the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `RPI_PROCEDURE_DELETE`$$


CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`serveraddress` TRIGGER `database`.`RPI_PROCEDURE_DELETE` AFTER DELETE

    ON `database`.`rpi_procedures`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `rpi_procedure_sequences`       WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_procedure_parts_dimensions`    WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_procedure_parts`       WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_additional`       WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_general`      WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_material`         WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_models`       WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_parts`        WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_specialty`        WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    DELETE FROM `rpi_contract_subcontract`      WHERE `id_procedure` = OLD.id_primary;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When a record is deleted in the stored proc, I need the trigger to fire to remove the references to that record in multiple tables. I know the trigger works because when I manually delete a record from the rpi_procedures table, the trigger does indeed fire and removes the records from the required tables. Is there something I am missing in the stored proc to get the trigger to work?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure what's wrong and just guessing... but hope it helps somehow. So... I can see four potential options here: 1-Trigger is cached and didn't get updated(flushed) for some reason; 2-you are on clustered mysql servers and by that, trigger is not present in every server instance(create it in all servers); 3-your SP's "IF live_ro... > 0 THEN" is never bigger than zero so Trigger don't fire; 4-WHERE clause always false (`id_primary` = id_primary_live;) so DELETE never happens.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter where the `DELETE` happens, the trigger should fire from the stored procedure. This begs the question, are you sure the `DELETE` is actually happening within the stored procedure, ie does the `COMMIT` actually happen?

As an alternative to your approach, if the tables are InnoDB, you could use [Foreign Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) on each of your tables that reference your `rpi_procedures.id_primary` column to have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that the foreign keys do the heavy lifting !!!

Comment: I am positive the delete is occurring (tested that functionality extensively). The person who originally designed / created the DB created the tables as MyISAM tables otherwise I would have definitely taken advantage of setting the Foreign Key constraints. We needed to get it done quick so I just threw the trigger code in the Stored Proc and called it a day. Not ideal, or how I would like to do it, but we needed it functional. Thanks!

Comment: That's interesting. It might be doing something funky since it is MyISAM, which doesn't support transactions (which you use in the stored procedure). Could you test to see if it works outside the `START TRANSACTION...COMMIT` block, but still within the stored procedure?